# read an address in memory from an external application

Tags: python-3.x, cpython

I'm developing a trainer for a game in python (for study purposes), I'm trying to read the value of an integer 4 byte address but I can't. Can anyone give me a hand?

I got this script but the output is in bytes and I can't decode it.

(my address is not a pointer, is a address)

```py
#-*- coding: cp1252 -*-

import ctypes, win32ui, win32process ,win32api

PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS = 0x1F0FFF
HWND = win32ui.FindWindow(None,"3D Pinball for Windows - Space Cadet").GetSafeHwnd()
print(HWND)
PID = win32process.GetWindowThreadProcessId(HWND)[1]
print(PID)
PROCESS = win32api.OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS,0,PID)

rPM = ctypes.windll.kernel32.ReadProcessMemory
wPM = ctypes.windll.kernel32.WriteProcessMemory

ADDRESS1 = 0x0475ECC4
ADDRESS2 = ctypes.create_string_buffer(64)
pi = ctypes.pointer(ADDRESS2)
rPM(PROCESS.handle,ADDRESS1,ADDRESS2,64,None)
valor = ADDRESS2.value
print(valor)
x=ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetLastError()
print(x)
```